Why my gdb can't read the file by stdin? (very weird)
This is t.c, I use gcc t.c -o t -m32 -g to compile it:
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char buffer[100];
    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    scanf("%99s", buffer);
    printf("You entered: %s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}

This is t.txt: 123
It can work well when I use pipeline or stdin in terminal:
muyigin@ysyx:~/Desktop$ cat t.txt | ./t
Please enter a string: You entered: 123
============================================
muyigin@ysyx:~/Desktop$ ./t < t.txt
Please enter a string: You entered: 123

BUT! It does't work in GDB, which seems it "can" work:
(gdb) file t
(gdb) run < t.txt
Starting program: /home/muyigin/Desktop/t1 < t.txt
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Please enter a string:

I have read many many answers since 2011, here are what I've tried:
(gdb) run < t.txt
(gdb) r < t.txt
(gdb) r < $(cat t.txt)
(gdb) r < /home/muyigin/Desktop/t.txt
(gdb) r < ~/Desktop/t.txt
(gdb) start < t.txt

And I've tried use breakpoint.
I use ubuntu22.04 in VMware 17 pro, gdb version is GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04.2) 12.1 

This should work (under Linux at least). Except apparently sometimes it doesn't, and no one knows why.

@n.m.couldbeanAI So How can I input a long string in GDB if this method doesn't work? especially I need to input the hexadecimal byte to practice the "stack overflow attack exercises".
Thanks for your generous help

This is most likely caused by something in your ~/.gdbinit. Try using gdb -nx ./t

@EmployedRussian Oh my fk genius god, it can work! I can't believe I just set ~/.gdbinit to pass the annoying welcome page last month, which will confuse me today!
Thanks a lot, I am wondering how could you find this answer? : )

I would never want to do that :)

This is most likely caused by something in your ~/.gdbinit.
Try using gdb -nx ./t.
